# ListView Error After Scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-listview, adapter, baseadapter

I Have A `ListView` for displaying some questions in my application. When my `ListView` displayed at first time before I scroll it, everything looks right, untill I scroll down and Scroll up in my `ListView`, several view in list from  my `ListView` is change as below :

```
1. ListView before Scroll
```

[image: ListView before Scroll]

```
2.ListView After Fisrt Scroll
```

[image: ListView After Fisrt Scroll]

```
 3. ListView After next Scroll
```

[image: ListView After next Scroll]

I have no Idea why this is happen to my `ListView`, I have searched many solutions, but it seems not really helps me, this is my code to call my adapter :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inisialisasi layout utama
     kuisioner = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_quisioner, container, false);
     //ListView
     list_tt = (ListView)kuisioner.findViewById(R.id.list_tt);
     //list
     listQuisioner = new ArrayList<ModelListQues>();
     lisLabelQues = new ArrayList<ModelLabelQues>();
     me=((ModelESPAJ)getActivity().getApplication());
     helper=new DBSpaj(getActivity());
     onLoadList();
     Adapter_Quisioner adapter_Quisioner = new Adapter_Quisioner(getActivity(), listQuisioner, lisLabelQues);
     if(list_tt.getCount()!=listQuisioner.size()){
     list_tt.setAdapter(adapter_Quisioner);
     }
     return kuisioner;
    }
```

This code for set my adapter :

```
public class Adapter_Quisioner extends BaseAdapter{
    Context context;
    int count;
    ArrayList <ModelListQues>listQuisioner;
    ArrayList <ModelLabelQues>lisLabelQues;

    public  Adapter_Quisioner(Context context, ArrayList <ModelListQues>listQuisioner, ArrayList <ModelLabelQues>lisLabelQues){
        this.context = context;
        this.listQuisioner = listQuisioner;
        this.lisLabelQues = lisLabelQues;
        this.count=listQuisioner.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return count;
    }
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return listQuisioner.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

//       convertView = null;
        View view= convertView;
        Holder holder= null;

        if (view==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_questformat, parent,false);

            holder=new Holder();
            //linear layout
            holder.layout_label_kesehatan = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layout_label_kesehatan);
            holder.layout_label_kesehatan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.layout_jawaban_kesehatan = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layout_jawaban_kesehatan);
            holder.layout_jawaban_kesehatan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.layout_label_pp = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layout_label_pp);
            holder.layout_label_pp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.lay_inputtext_qu = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.lay_inputtext_qu);
            holder.lay_inputtext_qu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //imageview
            holder.img_val_qu = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_val_qu);
            //textview
            holder.judul_qu= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.judul_qu);
            holder.judul_qu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.text_val_qu= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_val_qu);
            holder.text_val_qu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.number_qu= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.number_qu);
            holder.isi_qu= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.isi_qu);

            holder.isi_qu_ya= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.isi_qu_ya);
            holder.isi_qu_ya.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.initial_pp= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.initial_pp);
            holder.initial_pp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.initial_tt= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.initial_tt);
            holder.initial_tt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.initial_tt1= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.initial_tt1);
            holder.initial_tt1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.initial_tt2= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.initial_tt2);
            holder.initial_tt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.initial_tt3= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.initial_tt3);
            holder.initial_tt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.initial_input_qu_1= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.initial_input_qu_1);
            holder.initial_input_qu_1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.initial_input_qu_2= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.initial_input_qu_2);
            holder.initial_input_qu_2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //edittext
            holder.essay_qu= (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.essay_qu);
            holder.essay_qu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.essay_qu_ya= (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.essay_qu_ya);
            holder.essay_qu_ya.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.input_qu_1= (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.input_qu_1);
            holder.input_qu_1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.input_qu_2= (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.input_qu_2);
            holder.input_qu_2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //radiogroup
            holder.option_grup_qu= (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.option_grup_qu);
            holder.option_grup_qu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.option_grup_qu_pp= (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.option_grup_qu_pp);
            holder.option_grup_qu_pp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.option_grup_qu_tt= (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.option_grup_qu_tt);
            holder.option_grup_qu_tt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.option_grup_qu_tt1= (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.option_grup_qu_tt1);
            holder.option_grup_qu_tt1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.option_grup_qu_tt2= (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.option_grup_qu_tt2);
            holder.option_grup_qu_tt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.option_grup_qu_tt3= (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.option_grup_qu_tt3);
            holder.option_grup_qu_tt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //RadionButton
            holder.option_label_y= (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.option_label_y);
            holder.option_label_y.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.option_label_n= (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.option_label_n);
            holder.option_label_n.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.option_label_y_pp= (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.option_label_y_pp);
            holder.option_label_y_pp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.option_label_n_pp= (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.option_label_n_pp);
            holder.option_label_n_pp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.option_label_y_tt= (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.option_label_y_tt);
            holder.option_label_y_tt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.option_label_n_tt= (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.option_label_n_tt);
            holder.option_label_n_tt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.option_label_y_tt1= (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.option_label_y_tt1);
            holder.option_label_y_tt1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.option_label_n_tt1= (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.option_label_n_tt1);
            holder.option_label_n_tt1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.option_label_y_tt2= (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.option_label_y_tt2);
            holder.option_label_y_tt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.option_label_n_tt2= (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.option_label_n_tt2);
            holder.option_label_n_tt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.option_label_y_tt3= (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.option_label_y_tt3);
            holder.option_label_y_tt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.option_label_n_tt3= (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.option_label_n_tt3);
            holder.option_label_n_tt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder=(Holder)view.getTag();
        }
        //set judul Quisioner
        String judul = "";
        String Question = listQuisioner.get(position).getQUESTION();

        holder.number_qu.setText(listQuisioner.get(position).getQUESTION_NUMBER());
        //Pemegang Polis
        if(listQuisioner.get(position).getQUESTION_TYPE_ID()==1){
            holder.layout_label_pp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.lay_inputtext_qu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            judul = "     PEMEGANG POLIS";
        }
        //Tertanggung
        if(listQuisioner.get(position).getQUESTION_TYPE_ID()==2){
            holder.layout_label_pp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.lay_inputtext_qu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            judul = "     TERTANGGUNG";
        }
        //Kesehatan
        if(listQuisioner.get(position).getQUESTION_TYPE_ID()==3){
            holder.layout_label_kesehatan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.layout_jawaban_kesehatan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            judul = "     DATA KESEHATAN";
        }
        //check untuk judul
        if (position == 0){
            holder.judul_qu.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            holder.judul_qu.setText(judul);
        }else{
            if (lisLabelQues.get(position).getQUESTION_TYPE_ID() == listQuisioner.get(position-1).getQUESTION_TYPE_ID()){
                holder.judul_qu.setVisibility(view.GONE);
            }else {
                holder.judul_qu.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                holder.judul_qu.setText(judul);
            }
        }

        //looping for labels

            for(int i = 0; i<lisLabelQues.size(); i++){
                if(lisLabelQues.get(i).getQUESTION_TYPE_ID() == listQuisioner.get(position).getQUESTION_TYPE_ID()){
                    if(lisLabelQues.get(i).getQUESTION_ID() == listQuisioner.get(position).getQUESTION_ID()){
                        switch (lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_TYPE()) {
                        case 0:
                            if(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_ORDER()==1){
                            holder.essay_qu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            if(listQuisioner.get(position).getQUESTION().contains("\nJika Tidak, jelaskan ...\nJika Ya")){
                                Question = Question.substring(0,Question.lastIndexOf("\nJika Ya"));
                            }
                            holder.isi_qu.setText(Question);
                            }
                            if(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_ORDER()==2){
                            holder.isi_qu_ya.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Question = listQuisioner.get(position).getQUESTION();
                            if(listQuisioner.get(position).getQUESTION().contains("\nJika Tidak, jelaskan ...\nJika Ya")){
                            Question = Question.substring(Question.lastIndexOf("Jika Ya"));
                            holder.isi_qu_ya.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            holder.isi_qu_ya.setText(Question);
                            }
                        break;

                        case 1:
                            if(listQuisioner.get(position).getQUESTION_TYPE_ID()==3){

                                if(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_GROUP()==1){
                                    holder.option_grup_qu_pp.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                                    holder.initial_pp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    if(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_ORDER()==1){
                                            holder.option_label_y_pp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            holder.option_label_y_pp.setText(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_LABEL());
                                        }else{
                                            holder.option_label_n_pp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            holder.option_label_n_pp.setText(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_LABEL());
                                        }
                                    }

                                if(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_GROUP()==2){
                                    holder.option_grup_qu_tt.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                                    holder.initial_tt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    if(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_ORDER()==1){
                                            holder.option_label_y_tt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            holder.option_label_y_tt.setText(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_LABEL());
                                        }else{
                                            holder.option_label_n_tt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            holder.option_label_n_tt.setText(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_LABEL());
                                        }
                                    }

                                if(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_GROUP()==3){
                                    holder.option_grup_qu_tt1.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                                    holder.initial_tt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    if(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_ORDER()==1){
                                            holder.option_label_y_tt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            holder.option_label_y_tt1.setText(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_LABEL());
                                        }else{
                                            holder.option_label_n_tt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            holder.option_label_n_tt1.setText(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_LABEL());
                                        }
                                    }

                                if(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_GROUP()==4){
                                    holder.option_grup_qu_tt2.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                                    holder.initial_tt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    if(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_ORDER()==1){
                                            holder.option_label_y_tt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            holder.option_label_y_tt2.setText(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_LABEL());
                                        }else{
                                            holder.option_label_n_tt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            holder.option_label_n_tt2.setText(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_LABEL());
                                        }
                                    }

                                if(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_GROUP()==5){
                                    holder.option_grup_qu_tt3.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                                    holder.initial_tt3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    if(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_ORDER()==1){
                                            holder.option_label_y_tt3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            holder.option_label_y_tt3.setText(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_LABEL());
                                        }else{
                                            holder.option_label_n_tt3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            holder.option_label_n_tt3.setText(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_LABEL());
                                        }
                                    }

                                }else{
                                    holder.option_grup_qu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    if(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_ORDER()==1){
                                        holder.option_label_y.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        holder.option_label_y.setText(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_LABEL());
                                    }else{
                                        holder.option_label_n.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        holder.option_label_n.setText(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_LABEL());
                                    }
                            }   
                        break;

                        case 2:
                        break;

                        case 3:
                        break;

                        case 4:
                            if(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_ORDER()==1){
                                holder.input_qu_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.initial_input_qu_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.initial_input_qu_1.setText(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_LABEL());
                            }else{
                                holder.input_qu_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.initial_input_qu_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.initial_input_qu_2.setText(lisLabelQues.get(i).getOPTION_LABEL());
                            }
                        break;

                        case 5:
                        break;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        return view;
    }

    private  class Holder {
        public LinearLayout layout_label_kesehatan, layout_jawaban_kesehatan, layout_label_pp, lay_inputtext_qu;
        public ImageView img_val_qu;
        public TextView text_val_qu, number_qu, isi_qu, initial_pp, initial_tt, initial_tt1, initial_tt2, initial_tt3, initial_input_qu_1, 
        initial_input_qu_2,isi_qu_ya,judul_qu;
        public EditText essay_qu, input_qu_1, input_qu_2,essay_qu_ya;
        public RadioGroup option_grup_qu, option_grup_qu_pp, option_grup_qu_tt, option_grup_qu_tt1, option_grup_qu_tt2, option_grup_qu_tt3;
        public RadioButton option_label_y, option_label_n, option_label_y_pp, option_label_n_pp, option_label_y_tt, option_label_n_tt,
        option_label_y_tt1, option_label_n_tt1, option_label_y_tt2, option_label_n_tt2, option_label_y_tt3, option_label_n_tt3;

    }

}
```

So is there something wrong in my code? I hope someone can helps me. thank you.

Comment: For one, you're not using the ViewHolder pattern correctly at all.  You're supposed to do the findViewById() in the ViewHolder and not in the adapter's getView() method.  Beyond that you're just suffering from a view recycling issue ... see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(view == null){

## don't make any view GONE here

}else{

}
## Play with visibility or GONE for every view here.This will solve your problem

holder.option_label_y_tt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
holder.option_label_y_tt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
holder.option_label_y_tt1.setVisibility(View.GONE); and more...

Then rest of your code
```